# Android App Crashes after splashscreen - Android Studio

Tags: android

at the moment I am starting to build an android app and when I run it, after the splash screen it crashes.

Here is my error:

> 11-07 20:11:55.344    1273-1273/com.patrickmelia.bcrfm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.patrickmelia.bcrfm, PID: 1273
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 603288012 byte allocation with 1569794 free bytes and 61MB until OOM
>               at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:758)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:724)
>               at com.patrickmelia.bcrfm.CustomDrawerAdapter.getView(CustomDrawerAdapter.java:56)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
>               at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
>               at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
>               at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
>               at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:911)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>               at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
>               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Here is my activity code:

```
public class splashScreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 6000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    /*if(!isNetworkAvailable())
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("No Internet Access")
                .setMessage("Whoops, Internet Required. Please connect to the internet and try again")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();

    }else{*/

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(splashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            splashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            splashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}}
```

Has anyone got this error before/can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: How big is the image on your splash screen ?

Comment: It says on your logcat: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` which means your app used up all the RAM.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I have the image set to `android:layout_width="250dp", android:layout_height="200dp"` but when I created the logo, the size is 145px x 145px.

@jyoon cool thanks.

Comment: Not the layout params but size in MB ?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri sorry, 11.8 Kb

Answer (score 0):

You should resize down the image you are loading in your Layout. Also, making several images for different densities will help you to avoid this kind of problems.

Answer (score -1):

I had this trouble. You have to possible solutions: resize your image if high resolution is not mandatory or write this in AndroidManifest.xml on your application tag:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Second one worked for me.